# Is there any way to highlight all words of multiple words different colors in a pdf document?

Tags: pdf

It does not have to be a pdf document; some other format that a pdf could be converted to would also work. I would not be against having to make the software myself, so if there any any existing libraries that can do something like this or have the capable tools to do so would be great.

The idea is to have a dictionary like this:

```
"highlight color" to "word" for multiple colors and words
```

Comment: I think I found three Java libraries that I can use to do what I want. Too bad there is no real solution.

Comment: PDFBox looks like a very good tool for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

The easisest way is to write a custom string finder then adapt it to highlight the string(s).

One multi type document programmable library is MuPDF which has on Windows several single exe(s) to process multiple document types especially PDF.

Thus we can invoke `Mutool run find.js "filename.pdf" "string"` and adapt that to highlight the strings with a colour for each found. say we search this pages question as a PDF for "word" count and position.

`....mupdf\1.19.1\mutool.exe" run "find.js" "question.pdf" 1 "word string"`

result **NOTE using version 1.19.1** as the last to use this syntax on both 32 and 64 bit Windows systems (there was a breaking change in 1.20 +.)

```
warning: undefined link destination
        Be aware these are from Top Left Top Down in default PDF units (normally 1/72")
Position 1:     x = 291.997314453125    y = 90.68339538574219   W = 40.930938720703128  H = 24.240676879882814
Position 2:     x = 437.68792724609377  y = 90.68339538574219   W = 40.930938720703128  H = 24.240676879882814
Position 3:     x = 188.70480346679688  y = 273.9330749511719   W = 19.30328369140625   H = 8.774993896484375
Position 4:     x = 333.4922180175781   y = 273.9330749511719   W = 19.303253173828126  H = 8.774993896484375
Position 5:     x = 271.1244812011719   y = 424.8809509277344   W = 19.70745849609375   H = 11.67144775390625
Position 6:     x = 349.66943359375     y = 437.03094482421877  W = 19.70745849609375   H = 11.67144775390625
Position 7:     x = 168.11524963378907  y = 449.85595703125     W = 21.2091064453125    H = 11.67144775390625
Position 8:     x = 243.36720275878907  y = 449.85595703125     W = 21.209121704101564  H = 11.67144775390625
Position 9:     x = 407.9195861816406   y = 464.9580993652344   W = 19.303314208984376  H = 8.774993896484375
warning: ... repeated 2 times...
```

Here is an outline of that first part "find.js". I have only set it to find per single page as its then easy to reuse the function different ways in loops.
Newer versions e.g. current 1.23.0 (Windows zip with tesseract inbuilt) can found at https://mupdf.com/releases/index.html

```
//BEWARE this script was for older Version 1.19.1 see below for more recent.
if (scriptArgs.length != 3) {
    print('usage: mutool run Find.js "input.pdf" page# "word string"');
    quit();
}
var doc = new Document(scriptArgs[0], "application/pdf");
// var numpages = doc.countPages() // Not Yet Implimented, but will be needed for whole file loop all pages
var page = doc.loadPage(scriptArgs[1] -1); // loads the #-1 page of the document NOTE PDF counts pages from 0
var transform = [1,0,0,1,0,0]; //use default for 1 page unit per point may need modify for /UserUnit

var arr = page.search(scriptArgs[2], 500); // max_hits – Integer Defaults to 500 unless otherwise specified search is case insensitive
    print('\tBe aware these are from Top Left Top Down in default PDF units \(normally 1/72\"\)');
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var p = arr[i];
    print('Position ' + (i + 1) + ':\tx = ' + p[0] +  '\ty = ' + p[1] + '\tW = ' + (p[2] - p[0]) +  '\tH = ' + (p[5] - p[1]) );
}
```

OK but the OP needs those highlighted like this and repeatable for color.
[image]

So we just need to boost find.js to highlight.js, well about one day later here is the running concept, where we can run in a `for loop` on as many pages as desired.

```
"...mupdf\1.19.1\mutool.exe" run "highlights.js" "question.pdf" 1 "word" "output1.pdf" 1.0 0.0 1.0
"...mupdf\1.19.1\mutool.exe" run "highlights.js" "output1.pdf" 1 "color" "output2.pdf" 1.0 0.5 0.0
```

**highlights.js**

```
// THIS VERSION WORKS WITH MuTools 1.20.0 (LAST 32 bit or newer 64 bit) not the older version 1.19.1 syntax which is shown for legacy users.
if (scriptArgs.length != 7) {
    print('usage: mutool run Highlights.js "input.pdf" page# "word string" "output.pdf" R.# G.# B.# \(e.g. orange = 1.0 0.5 0.0\)');
    quit();
}
var doc = new Document(scriptArgs[0], "application/pdf");
// var numpages = doc.countPages() // Not Yet Implimented, but will be needed for whole file loop all pages
var page = doc.loadPage(scriptArgs[1] -1); // loads the #-1 page of the document NOTE PDF counts pages from 0
var transform = [1,0,0,1,0,0]; //use default for 1 page unit per point may need modify for /UserUnit

var arr = page.search(scriptArgs[2], 500); // max_hits – Integer Defaults to 500 unless otherwise specified search is case insensitive
    print('\tBe aware these are from Top Left Top Down in default PDF units \(normally 1/72\"\)');
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var p = arr[i];

        //Version 1.19.1
        //print('Position ' + (i + 1) + ':\tx = ' + p[0] +  '\ty = ' + p[1] + '\tW = ' + (p[2] - p[0]) +  '\tH = ' + (p[5] - p[1]) );

        //Version 1.20.0
        print('Position ' + (i + 1) + ': Quad=' + p[0])

        var annot = page.createAnnotation("Highlight");
        annot.setColor([scriptArgs[4], scriptArgs[5], scriptArgs[6]]);

        //Version 1.19.1
        //annot.setQuadPoints([[p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7]]]);  

        //Version 1.20.0
        annot.setQuadPoints(p);
}
page.update();

doc.save(scriptArgs[3], "pretty,ascii,compress-images,compress-fonts")
```

Comment: That is a really cool concept. I do want it to run on Windows, too, without mingw. I was thinking of implementing a Mozilla firefox plugin. It seems easy, so I might try implementing it by this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is go to the menu and select find and it will highlight the searched word you can than hight words by the searched words

Apps
UPDF by clicking the download button below. Launch the UPDF on your device and click on the "Open File" button to import the PDF file
On the left, you can click on the "Comment" select the "Highlight" tool, choose a color, and drag the tool over the text you want to highlight. As soon as you leave the cursor, your text will be highlighted.

Comment: That is incredibly slow. Is there not a software solution?